# function happens before onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am eventually trying to set this up so that when a header is clicked on, it will sort the table. For now I just want it to alert("Hello world") to insure I have it setup correctly. Currently "myFunction" occurs when the page is loaded. I would like for it to occur when the button is pushed. Thanks for any help. Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">

                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="catTable"></div>
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script>


                function renderData(cats){
                        var output='<table id="indextable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
                        output+="<thead>"
                        output+="<tr>";
                        output+="<th> HeadShot </th>";
                        output+="<th> Breed </th>";  
                        output+="<th><button onclick='" + myFunction() + "'>Country</button></th>"; // myFunction happens when page is loaded 
                        output+="<th> CoffeePreference </th>";
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</thead>"

                    for (var i in cats) {
                        output+="<tbody>" 

                        output+="<tr>";
                        output+="<td><img src='" + cats[i].picture+"' alt='missing cat picture'></td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].breed + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].country + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].coffeePreference + "</td>"
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</tbody>" 

                    }
                    output+="</table>";
                    document.getElementById("catTable").innerHTML=output;
                }            



                function getData(){       
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                        var cats = cats;
                        sortData(cats, 'coffeePreference');    
                    });
                }

                function sortData(cats, element){
                    switch(element) {
                        case 'breed':
                            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.breed < b.breed) ? -1 : 1;});
                            renderData(cats);
                            break;
                        case 'country':
                            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? -1 : 1;});
                            renderData(cats);
                            break;
                        case 'coffeePreference':
                            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.coffeePreference < b.coffeePreference) ? -1 : 1;});
                            renderData(cats);
                        default:
                            renderData(cats);
                    }

                }

            function myFunction() {
                alert("Hello World");
            }
                getData();

                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. The problem is with this line:

```
output+="<th><button onclick='" + myFunction() + "'>Country</button></th>";
```

It should be:

```
output+="<th><button onclick='myFunction()'>Country</button></th>";
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because this line

```
<button onclick='" + myFunction() + "'>Country</button></th>
```

That will invoke the function immediately. You don't need string concatenation here, just write it in:

```
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Country</button></th>
```